# SQL Pass a string to a Stored Procedure that is not a Column Name

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters

Can I pass a String to a Stored Procedure that is not a Column Name?

I need to call the StoredProcedure from C#.

The following does not work as the parameter can't be defined without it's Type, but shows what I am trying to do. Problem is that Sql is looking at @stringToIdentifyDataTable as a ColumnName, which seems fair, but not what I am trying to do.

```
Alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[PutNewTypeSource] @stringToIdentifyDataTable, 
@ID int, @Description varchar(50), @Active bit
AS
DECLARE 
@Query AS VARCHAR(MAX), 
@Field_Out AS VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @Field_Out = CASE @stringToIdentifyDataTable
                        WHEN 'ReferralSource' THEN '[Adm].[JobReferralSource]'
                        WHEN 'ReferralSource2' THEN '[Adm].[JobReferralSource2]'
                    END 

SET @Query = concat('
IF EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM ',@Field_Out,' WHERE Description= ',@Description,')
    BEGIN
        UPDATE ',@Field_Out,
        'SET Active = ',@Active,
        'WHERE Description= ',@Description,';
    END')

EXEC (@Query)


exec [PutNewTypeSource] 'ReferralSource', 1, 'Description1', 0
```

Comment: You can't pass a column name as a parameter in the first place

Comment: If you want to know whether a variable needs a type, then yes, `@stringToIdentifyDataTable` needs a type.

Comment: If you must, then you do need to use dynamic SQL. But not like that: [Dos and Don'ts of Dynamic SQL](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/dos-and-donts-of-dynamic-sql)

Comment: That `IF EXISTS` is meaningless. The UPDATE clause will only update rows that match the description anyway.

Comment: You haven't specified a type for the `@stringToIdentifyDataTable` parameter.

Comment: Thanks. Just making sure I wasn't missing something.

Comment: Procedures like this are always a massive code smell. Why do you have two tables that are so interchangeable they require a single procedure? WHy not use a single table with a column to differentiate between types of rows? Or if they are very different tables, why do you need a single procedure to update them? Why not just have two (or more) procedures?

Comment: "Problem is that Sql is looking at @stringToIdentifyDataTable as a ColumnName"  What makes you think that?

Answer (score 0):

***If*** I understand correctly what you could do is this. note that I properly quote your object, and **importantly** parametrise you parameters. What you have before was wide open to injection:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PutNewTypeSource] @Referral varchar(50), @Description varchar(50), @Active bit --I remvoed @ID as it was never used
AS BEGIN

    DECLARE @Schema sysname,
            @Table sysname;
    SET @Schema = CASE WHEN @Referral IN ('ReferralSource','ReferralSource2') THEN N'adm' END;
    SET @Table = CASE @Referral WHEN 'ReferralSource' THEN N'JobReferralSource'
                                WHEN 'ReferralSource2' THEN N'JobReferralSource2' END;

    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

    SET @SQL = N'UPDATE ' + QUOTENAME(@Schema) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@Table) + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
               N'SET Active = @Active' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
               N'WHERE Description= @Description;';

    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@Description varchar(50), @Active bit', @Description = @Description, @Active = @Active;
END;
```